# Yii dir separator //

Tags: yii

I have seen this line of code in Yii when playing with layout:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
```

Normally I only see single forward slash, but now double. And, when I remove one forward slash in the above code, the output display didn't change at all.

So, could you tell me why Yii using double slashes instead of single slash? And does them return the same resutl?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In Yii context and this example `//layouts/main` will be rendered to `protected/views/layouts/main.php`. It's path to your layouts folder.

You want to use double slashes if there is non-default layout directory.
For example if you have two folders `layouts` and `layouts-fancy` under protected/views/{here}
You can switch to fancy layouts by prefix path with '//'. By default Yii will be using `layouts` (see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#layout).

For better testing create new layout `protected/views/layout-fancy/main.php` and add variable `public $layout = '//layout-fancy/main.php';` to your base Controller.php and see what happen.